# Nothing happens when my dwellers explore the wasteland

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem, and how to fix it. When I send my dwellers out into the wasteland absolutely nothing happens. I sent one dweller out for 8 hours and still nothing happened to him and he didn't bring back anything.

Comment: Do you mean quite literally there is absolutely nothing in the log message log? Or is it that he simply does not find any items?

Comment: Did you recall the dweller? They will just stay out there in the ---fresh--- air until you do.

Comment: Yes there is nothing in the message log, and when I recall them they just show up at the vault with nothing to collect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you turn your phone's timer ahead for some reason? Chances are that is the cause of your issue if you did. If that is indeed the case, I am not certain of this but, after the amount of time you jumped passes your explorer should start encountering creatures and collecting loot again.

Comment: Xinsanegamer17- "yes that is the exact prob and I did set the time forward for to skip something and skipped a year lol so I must wait till February next year to use my dweller again but I do the objectives to get stuff..."

Comment: Its also worth noting that if you send out your explorers **before** fast forwarding the clock, the added time should also add to the explorers time, in the wasteland. This can be a helpful tactic, as the longer they are in the wasteland, the better the chance of finding good gear.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to my problem; I started my shelter on an airplane with no internet connection, my iPad in Eastern time. When i arrived and got internet, my iPad switched to Central as you would expect. Is it true that the game doesn't handle time zones either?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without waiting for next year?

Comment: You would either have to reset your game or you can decrypt and edit your save file with [FOSDecrypt](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3gvrga/fallout_shelter_how_to_backup_or_transfer_your/) to reset the timer. Depending on how far into the game you are editing might be worth the trouble; if not just reset your game and start over.